# yii2-fotorama-widget не роботает в модалке

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

Проект на Yii2 basic віджет yii2-fotorama-widget норм роботает в админке а вот на главной в модалке проблема почемуто не роботает

вот подключил модалку віджетом в index

```
 <?php \yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
     //'header' => 'Детальна інформація:',
    'footer' => '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Закрити</button>',
    'id' => 'info-work',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',

 ]);


 \yii\bootstrap\Modal::end()?>
```

и вот виджет вивожу с странице https://github.com/MetalGuardian/yii2-fotorama-widget

```
 <?php 
     $fotorama = \metalguardian\fotorama\Fotorama::begin(
         [
             'options' => [
             'loop' => true,
             'hash' => true,
             'ratio' => 800/600,
        ],
        'spinner' => [
            'lines' => 20,
        ],
        'tagName' => 'span',
        'useHtmlData' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => [
            'class' => 'custom-class',
            'id' => 'custom-id',
        ],
    ]
); 
?>
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">    
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/2.jpg">
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/3.jpg">
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/4.jpg">
    <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/5.jpg">
<?php $fotorama->end(); ?>
```

в результате картинки есть но карусель не роботает...

для модалки у меня другая view так как через ajax роботаю

```
public function actionFullJob(){

    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $portfolio = Portfolio::findOne($id);

    if (empty($portfolio)){
        return false;

    }else{
        $this->layout = false;

        return $this->render('portfolio-modal', [
            'portfolio' => $portfolio
        ]);

    }

}
```

возможно в модалку надо както передать что то?

вот запрос:

```
$('.info-work').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Відміна стандартного переходу ссилки
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    // var fotorama = $fotoText.data('fotorama');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'site/full-job',
        data: {id:id},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res){
            if(!res){
                alert('Увага! Виникла помилка!')
            }
            // fotorama.show();
            $('#info-work .modal-body').html(res);
            $('#info-work').modal('show');

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error');
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('.loading').hide();

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас скорее всего не подгружаются скрипты, попробуйте ипользовать [renderAjax()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#renderAjax()-detail) вместо render() И папку assets не забудьте очистить на всякий случай.